# Case expression with multiple results

Tags: sql, case

I am looking for a way to actually create some duplication in my results in MS SQL Server.  I understand that typically you are looking for ways to not create duplication, but in this examples I need all the individual rows returned.

I am working with a table with about 10 million rows and 33 columns. The table consists of an ID in the first column and the remainder of the columns have either 'Y' or 'NULL' in them - a HUGE majority of the columns are NULL.

Of the 10 million rows 8 million of them only have a single 'Y' per row with the remaining 2 million rows having more than one column with a 'Y' in a row.

For the rows with a single 'Y' a basic case expression works perfectly fine to create a single column of results .

Here is my problem though - I want two rows, one for each 'Y' if there is more than one 'Y' in a row.

Below is a small de-identified sample.

```
ID        FLAG1   FLAG2         FLAG3       FLAG4   FLAG5
188       NULL    NULL          NULL        NULL    NULL
194       Y       NULL          NULL        NULL    NULL
200       Y       NULL          NULL        NULL    Y
```

I am attempting to use a Case Expression like this.

```
Select 
ID
,Case 
    When [FLAG1] = 'Y'
    Then 'FLAG1'
    When [FLAG2] = 'Y'
    Then 'FLAG2'      
End as 'Service_Line'
```

What I want is a result that looks like this.

```
ID     Service_Line
194    FLAG1
200    FLAG1
200    FLAG5
```

My problem is that the Case expression only returns the first result so I end up with this.

```
ID     Service_Line
194    FLAG1
200    FLAG1
```

Is a Case Expression appropriate for what I am trying to accomplish or should I be trying to go about this some other way?

Comment: What DB system are you using (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, etc)? This may make a difference to the features available to you to solve problems like this in an elegant way.

Comment: Edit your question and specify the database you are using.

Comment: Check if your RDBMS supports UNPIVOT.

Comment: I was also investigating UNPIVOT, which I have used in other scenarios but for some reason I can't get it to apply to this data appropriately for some reason, probably user error.

Comment: Still you havent told us your rdbms. Sql Server, MySql, Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

A `case` is not appropriate.  A general SQL approach would be:

```
select id, 'FLAG1' as flag
from t
where flag1 = 'Y'
union all
select id, 'FLAG2' as flag
from t
where flag2 = 'Y'
union all
select id, 'FLAG3' as flag
from t
where flag3 = 'Y'
. . .
```

There are other (more efficient) methods, but those depend on the database you are using.

I should note:  `case` is the right approach if you want the values in a single row:

```
select id,
       concat( case when flag1 = 'Y' then 'FLAG1 ' else '' end,
               case when flag2 = 'Y' then 'FLAG2 ' else '' end,
               case when flag3 = 'Y' then 'FLAG3 ' else '' end,
               . . .
             ) as flags
from t;
```

Of course, the syntax for `concat()` can vary among databases (`concat()` itself is ANSI standard).  You can also trim off the last space.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but this results in the the two items in a single cell.  I am looking for a row for each item as opposed to concatenating them into a single cell.

Comment: Your first option appears to be working though.  I will circle back with updates.